# Exclamation mark in python

Tags: python

Hi I am curious about how you can describe a exclamation mark in python in a for loop.

```
Input : 145
Output : It's a Strong Number.
Explanation : Number = 145
145 = 1! + 4! + 5!
145 = 1 + 24 + 120
```

```py
def exponent(n):
 res = 0
 for i in str(n):
 a = int(i)
 
 res = res + (#exclamation mark)
 return res
```

I have tried the code a above but I get a little bit stuck.

Comment: 4! means factorial of 4. You need to calculate the factorial of each digits and check if their sum is same as the number itself

Comment: You could use `math.factorial()` to calculate those factorials (unless it is part of your homework to do it yourself).

Comment: The code is written by myself I only want to know if there is a way to calculate the factorial of each digit without the math.factorial function

Comment: @OR you can implement it yourself, trivial implementation will work well for single digit inputs.

Comment: @OR If that is your actual question, you should add it to your question.   Google how to calculate factorials, it's the product of descending numbers e.g. 4! = 4x3x2x1, you should be able to implement that in a loop

Comment: A recursive function to calculate the factorial takes only a few lines of Python and the code can be easily be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the np.math.factorial(n) for this.
Also notice that your "Output" does not really follow correct syntax and the ' sign is causing it to be evaluated as a comment.
You could do it like this:

```
Output = "It's a strong number."
```

For the main problem your trying to solve:

```
import numpy as np
number = 7
result = np.math.factorial(number) # = 7*6*5*4*3*2*1
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `np.math` is just built-in `math`, why adding a dependency for using a built-in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the factorial, you can just do

```py
import math
math.factorial(4)  # returns 24
```

If you don't want to use `math.factorial` as you said [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518291/exclamation-mark-in-python#comment131542570_74518291), you can easily make your own factorial function like so:

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return factorial(n - 1) * n

factorial(4)  # returns 24
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to MarcellPerger's answer, a more common way to implement factorial than the implementation shown is as follows

```
def factorial(n):
    k = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        k *= i
    return k
```

This has the twin advantages of being around twice as fast, and also not erroring for moderately large n.

There are many other ways in which factorial is implemented, each differing in their use cases, including memoised techniques and `functools.reduce`.